# How to add border on a container inside a row widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout, widget, border, flutter-layout

```
        Container(
    //            decoration: BoxDecoration(
    //              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black45),
    //              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
    //            ),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Text("hi"),
                      margin : EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 8, 8, 16),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.42,
                      height: 90,
                      color: Colors.black12,
                    ),

                    Container(
                      child: Text("Hi"),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 8, 16),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.42 ,
                      height: 90,
                      color: Colors.black12,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

I can add border using Box decoration on the outer container, but it's throwing me an error when I am trying to do the same on the inner containers. What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Please mention the error that you are getting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to add border on container inside row widget , we have to use decoration for the inner containers.
Once you will post the error, we can answer you better but i think the below code will be helpful for you.
If you are using decoration then you must not add colour attribute in container directly, it should be in decoration only.

```
     Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Text("hi"),
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 8, 8, 16),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.42,
                height: 90,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      width: 4,
                    )),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text("Hi"),
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 8, 16),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.42,
                height: 90,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      width: 4,
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: The required answer : WE must not add colour attribute in container directly, it should be in decoration only.

Comment: Right color is the property of the decoration item, never of tge container.

Comment: color parameter of container is used to set value of color in box decoration if it is null, color argument for container is just a shorthand for the decoration's color

Answer (score 1):

In container widgets you cannot use the `color` and `decoration` at the same time. Remove the `color` property from the `Container` and move it into the `BoxDecoration` widget

This should work:

```dart
Container(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black45),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          color: Colors.black12,  //add it here
        ),
        child: Text("hi"),
        margin : EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 8, 8, 16),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *0.42,
        height: 90,
        //color: Colors.black12,    //must be removed
      ),

      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black45),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          color: Colors.black12,  //add it here
        ),
        child: Text("Hi"),
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 8, 8, 16),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.42 ,
        height: 90,
        //color: Colors.black12,      // must be removed
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the humble Divider widget to keep things simple. If you add it to the bottom of a Column in your row it will add a line that will act as a border.

```
const Divider(height: 1.0,),
```